# Specifiy Font-Family Weight/Slant/Style?

Tags: html, css

So I'm using a font family for header text (Aileron to be specific), and the font family has various weights such as "Light", "Bold", "ExtraBold", and whatnot. How would you declare the specific weight in CSS?

This is my code:

```
h1{
    font-family:Aileron-Black;
    font-size:49pt;
    letter-spacing:-3px;
    color:white;
}
```

I would experiment with taking off the hyphen and putting the name of the family in quotation marks, but nothing seems to do the trick.

Comment: Could you show how you inclouded the font?

Comment: Umm, I just installed it to my computer, didn't really do anything with the document!

Comment: OK, so this website will only work on your PC, i thought you added it via font-face

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, incloude the font via CSS in Bold and Thin:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Aileron';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local('Aileron' ), url('path/to/font/Aileron.woff') format('woff'); }

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Aileron';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 800;
 src: local('Aileron-Black' ), url('path/to/font/Aileron-Black.woff') format('woff'); }
```

Then declare the font-weight you want to use by using the `font-weight` propety. 
For  **Bold font** use 800:

```
h1{ 
 font-family:'Aileron';
 font-size:49pt; 
 letter-spacing:-3px;
 color:white;
 font-weight: 800; }
```

**Or for thin font use 100:**

```
h1{ 
 font-family:'Aileron';
 font-size:49pt; 
 letter-spacing:-3px;
 color:white;
 font-weight: 100; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `font-weight` property, it takes either a numerical value or a keyword value (such as normal or bold). You need to look up in your CSS code for the `font-face` declaration of the font you are using, there you will see the specific `font-weight`.

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/) you can find more information.

Regarding your case:

```
h1{
    font-family: "Aileron";
    font-size:49pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing:-3px;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: So would this make sense?

h1{ 
font-face:Aileron;
font-weight:Thin;
}

Comment: In that case search for the font-face declaration of the "thin" version, there you will see the specific font-weight, for example: font-weight: 200.

Comment: OHH okay that makes sense, thank you so much! 
I was using Coda 2 as an IDE, and I saw the numbers and when you commented it totally clicked, thank you!

Comment: You should mark my answer as The answer :) I'm glad now you understand.